# How to read and write integers with a SeekableByteChannel in little endian format?

Tags: java, endianness, nio2

I need to read and write signed and unsigned integers with a SeekableByteChannel in little endian format. This may seem silly, but I cannot find something in the JDK. Have I missed something or am I expected to roll this on my own? This would be no problem, but I don't feel like reinventing the wheel today. :-)

Comment: Do you have any code at all? I don't see anything called SeekableByteChannel in the JDK, the nearest thing I can see to that in the nio package is WritableByteChannel.

Comment: This is java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel in JSE 7.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. Sorry, thought I looked through 6 and 7, but actually just looked through 6 twice..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a work for the [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).

Somewhat like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] payload = toArray(-1991249);
    int number = fromArray(payload);
    System.out.println(number);
}

public static  int fromArray(byte[] payload){
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(payload);
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    return buffer.getInt();
}

public static byte[] toArray(int value){
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    buffer.putInt(value);
    return buffer.array();
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, that's the missing link - thanks. Of course, I need ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN.

Comment: Okay, I probably need to write a decorator so that I can comfortably read and write unsigned integers.